# Intercept between rectangle and line drawn from center point

Tags: java, geometry, line, rectangles

Consider the following diagram
[image]

Given that A is the center point of the rectangle and the origin, and the coordinates for B, how do you find at what point Line AB intersects the rectangle?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as framed, it is a question of geometry.

Comment: where can i ask geometry questions?

Comment: Try math.stackexchange.com, but make sure you take their tour first before asking a question.  P.S. Please don't use the "java" tag on questions that have nothing to do with Java.

Answer (score 3):

Intersection coordinates relative to center (A point):

```
dx = B.X - A.X
dy = B.Y - A.Y
if Width * Abs(dy) < Height * Abs(dx) then
   x = Sign(dx) * Width / 2
   y = dy * x / dx
else
   y = Sign(dy) * Height / 2
   x = dx * y / dy
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use JTS Topology Suite (https://github.com/locationtech/jts):

```
// create a rectangle from center point, width and height
public static LinearRing createRectangle(Coordinate center, double width, double height){
    Coordinate upperLeft = new Coordinate(center.x - (width/2), center.y + (height/2));
    Coordinate upperRight = new Coordinate(center.x + (width/2), center.y + (height/2));
    Coordinate lowerRight = new Coordinate(center.x + (width/2), center.y - (height/2));
    Coordinate lowerLeft = new Coordinate(center.x - (width/2), center.y - (height/2));
    LinearRing rectangle = new GeometryFactory().createLinearRing(new Coordinate[]{upperLeft, upperRight, lowerRight, lowerLeft, upperLeft});
    return rectangle;
}

// calculate intersection
public static Coordinate getIntersectionFromRectangleCenterAndCoordinate(LinearRing rectangle, Coordinate someCoord){
    // get your rectangle center coordinate (A)
    Coordinate rectangleCenter = rectangle.getCentroid().getCoordinate();
    // create line from center to someCoord (A - B)
    LineString lineFromCenterToSomeCoord = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(new Coordinate[]{rectangleCenter, someCoord});
    // calculate intersection
    Geometry intersectionGeom = rectangle.intersection(lineFromCenterToSomeCoord);
    // in your case just one intersection point...
    Coordinate intersectionCoordinate = intersectionGeom.getCoordinate();
    return intersectionCoordinate;
}
```